# Find Country given some condition SQL

Tags: sql

I have this table and i want to search the name of the country that has product.available = FALSE and market.market_name = "ikea"

the table are this:

Market

| market_id | state_id |

|     01    |     1    |

|     02    |     3    |

|     03    |     3    |

|     04   |    12     |

isIn

| market_id | product_id |

|     02    |     112   |

|     01    |     116    |

|     03    |     117    |

|      04   |    111    |

Product

| product_id | available |

|     112     |    True   |

|     116     |   false   |

|     117     |   False   |

|     111     |    True   |

State

| state_id | name    |

| 1        | Italy   |

| 3        | France  |

| 5        | England |

| 12       | Germany |

MarketName

| market_id | market_name |

| 01        | IKEA        |

| 02        | MEDIA       |

| 03        | PLUS        |

| 04        | EURO        |

Output Italy

this is the picture of the structure of database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpi8M.jpg)

Comment: This seems pretty basic question . What have you tried, what did you research?

Comment: I do not understand how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to your question if you are running a Microsoft SQL Server:

```
declare @market table (market_id int, state_id int);

insert into @market (market_id, state_id)
values
    (1, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 12);

declare @isln table (market_id int, product_id int);
insert into @isln (market_id, product_id)
values
    (2, 112),
    (1, 116),
    (3, 117),
    (4, 111);

declare @product table (product_id int, available bit);
insert into @product (product_id, available)
values
    (112, 1),
    (116, 0),
    (117, 0),
    (111, 1);

declare @state table (state_id int, name nvarchar(20));
insert into @state (state_id, name)
values
    (1, N'Italy'),
    (3, N'France'),
    (5, N'England'),
    (12, N'Germany');

declare @marketName table (market_id int, market_name nvarchar(20));
insert into @marketName (market_id, market_name)
values
    (1, N'IKEA'),
    (2, N'MEDIA'),
    (3, N'PLUS'),
    (4, N'EURO');

select s.name
from
    @product as p
    inner join
        @isln as i
            on p.product_id = i.product_id
    inner join
        @marketName as mn
            on i.market_id = mn.market_id
    inner join
        @market as m
            on mn.market_id = m.market_id
    inner join
        @state as s
            on m.state_id = s.state_id
where
    p.available = 0
    and mn.market_name = N'IKEA';
```

...and the result is (as expected and asked for):

[image]

If you are not running an MS SQL Server then the answer should be something like this:

```
select s.name
from
    product as p
    inner join
        isin as i
            on p.product_id = i.product_id
    inner join
        marketName as mn
            on i.market_id = mn.market_id
    inner join
        market as m
            on mn.market_id = m.market_id
    inner join
        state as s
            on m.state_id = s.state_id
where
    p.available = 0
    and mn.market_name = 'IKEA';
```